# Wrong domain in uploads folder

Tags: images

I just changed my website's domain and the user profile pictures saved in `wp-content/uploads/...` still have the old domain in the url.
Example:

`https://www.olddomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/profile_pic.jpg`

And i want to change them all to

`https://www.newdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/profile_pic.jpg`

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: WordPress doesn't support profile photo uploads out of the box, how are you implementing this? How are the profile pic paths stored? It sounds like rather than using the attachment system it's storing actual URLs, and that's the problem

Comment: i think best way for you install duplicator plugin old domain and create package and download installer and zip file 2] upload this two file new domain and run installer. please check duplicator plugin vedio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will allow myself to expand on Ricks answer as there are a few ways to change old domain to new domain and each might be helpful depending on your situation.

1) use the **Better Search and Replace plugin** https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/ plugin as suggested in the answer above.

2) use **Database Search and Replace script** https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

You can easily upload it to your server via FTP and then delete once you replace the domain names.

It does not require WordPress to run just PHP and MySQL (so this can be plus or minus depending on your use case i suppose).

3) if you have access to **WP CLI (WordPress command line interface)** you can use the `wp search-replace` command to update the domain https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/

With WP CLI installed on your server already, this is the quickest way to do that i think and does not require installing anything.

4) do it manually in the database, but with so many tools available i would recommend selecting a solution from #1 to #3.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, the Better Search and Replace plugin did a great job at updating the `wp_usermeta` table that I found out later it was where those url's were "hiding" :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the URL in media records (or anywhere in the database), then a plugin like "Better Search and Replace" (my personal favorite that I use when moving sites) will easily replace the old URL with the new one. That is one of the steps that I do when moving a site to a new domain, or from a development system to the live system.

You can do it manually with commands via myPHPAdmin, but the plugin is much easier, IMHO. I usually install the plugin, run the search/replace, test, then remove the plugin.

Of course, a backup of your database before major operations is always a good idea.