# Some resources of my website are pointing to www.mysite.com/dev/ and trying to get rid of that append has been a headache

Tags: plugins, urls

**The problem:**

I'm in the process of migrating a website to another server, so the maintainer of that page gave me the code and the database, so I could install it on my server. The problem is that for some reason I can't see some .css files or images loading because some of them point to www.mywebsite.com/dev/ instead of www.mywebsite.com/.

**Solution I tried**:

I read that there's a plugin called Velvet Blues Update URLs, I installed it and I tried to change the url like it says in the instructions but I get 0 results when I try to change the URL so it doesn't change anything. I just get the following text:

```
ERROR: Something may have gone wrong.   
Your URLs have not been updated.

Results 
0 Content Items (Posts, Pages, Custom Post Types, Revisions)
0 Excerpts
0 Links
0 Attachments
0 Custom Fields
0 GUIDs
```

I then go to the sql dump file of the database and search for that string myself and I do find the /dev/ in many of the links, however I find the lilnks like "/home/mywebsite/public_html/dev/wp-content/plugins/remove-query-strings-from-static-resources/remove-query-strings.php", I tried to copy and paste this database into the plugin for example and it also get the same error as before.

I don't want to change the links directly on the database because I have heard that it would create some problems. Any ideas about how to be able to get rid of the /dev/ append?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your software for finding URLs in the database does not find any matches, it might be worth double-checking it with some other method, please see my reply here [Wrong domain in uploads folder](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/320512/wrong-domain-in-uploads-folder/320544#320544) for more details.

If the CSS file is one of your theme CSS files then most likely the CSS file URL is not stored in the database at all. I would advise checking your theme functions.php or header.php files, my guess is that either the CSS file URL is registered there (using wp_register_style()) function with the /dev/ path or loaded directly in the header.php.